# Can you load a groovy script in a declarative pipeline without assigning it to an object?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

From: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/workflow-cps/#load-evaluate-a-groovy-source-file-into-the-pipeline-script

```
def pipeline
node('slave') {
  pipeline = load 'pipeline.groovy'
  pipeline.functionA()
}

pipeline.functionB()
```

Rather than being able to access functions like: `pipeline.functionA()` - I want to be able to directly reference them. Something like:

```
node('slave') {
  load 'pipeline.groovy'
  functionA()
}

functionB()
```

Is something like this possible?

Comment: This looks a bit more like scripted syntax, but if you want to reference a function or method with a shorter name, then you can use custom steps from global variable methods: https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/shared-libraries/#defining-custom-steps. Does that look like what you want?

Comment: shared libraries are problematic bc I want my source (for the shared library) to be in the same github repo as my declartive pipeline script